# i am not able to upload my .exe and .msi files to my website.

Tags: hosting, web-hosting

i am not able to upload my .exe and .msi files to my website. i tried with ftp, cuteftp etc. Is it possible to upload .exe and .msi files to website? I even tried with both linux and windows server.

```
<html>
<body>
</body>
</hmtl>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "unable to upload"? Are you using FTP, WebDAV, Web Deploy? Note that many web-hosts will block executable files to prevent the spread of malware.

Comment: may we know which error are you facing? If you are unable to upload a file using FTP client then there must be a permission issue.

Comment: s. am getting the error as access denied... i talked with hosting provider and they said they dont permit .exe and msi files.. but i have seen in lot of local websites that they have the option of downloading exe and msi files from their website.. can anyone suggest some hosting providers who provide these options.. thanks in advance....